# multiple ajax requests with multiple data parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Pardon my long-winded explanations.... posting on SO helps me work through questions in my head :)

I have a main page with two separate DIVs.

A user enters a bunch of data into a textbox, then I have that data sent to the two pages which populate the two DIVs:

```
var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');  //create array from pasted data

$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'return.php',
      data: {lines:lines},        
        success:function(data){
        $("#info").html(data); //loads return.php with the data from *lines*                             
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'dropDown.php',
            data: {lines:lines},
            success: function(data){
            $("#dropdown").html(data); //loads dropDown.php with the data from *lines*
            }
            });                                      
        }
  });
```

`#info` populates with a table that has a bunch of generic data, while `#dropDown` populates with a dropdown of potential customers that utilize the part numbers that the user entered in the textbox.

**Everything works up to here**

My goal is to allow the user to select a customer from the dropdown, then have it change the data back in the `#info` div, but I can't figure out how to get **lines**

Using this code on dropDown.php

```
$_SESSION['lines'] = $_REQUEST['lines'];
 $q = $_SESSION['lines'][0];

$supplierQuery   = "SELECT DISTINCT supplier FROM table where partNumber = '$q'";
```

The dropdown populates correctly, and when the user selects a customer, this piece of code executes:

```
<select onChange="selectCustomer(this.value)">
```

This is where I lose it.

So far I have:

  Taken the original array **lists** and sent it off to two different .php pages.

  picked a specific customer using dropdown.php

Now I want to:

  Send both **lists** and this new variable **c** back to return.php

My function is as follows:

```
function selectCustomer(str) {
var id = str;
var lines = <?php echo $_SESSION['lines']; ?>;

$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'return.php',
      data: {'c':id , 'lines': lines},        
        success:function(data){
        $("#info").html(data);
        }
  });
```

}

**Issue**

When the function above runs, it doesn't pass anything back to return.php.

First off, when I `console.log(lines);`, I get

```
function Array() { [native code] }
```

Second, I'm trying to pass the variable `c` to return.php because I have this line in return.php

```
$c = $_GET['c']; // quote customer
```

Normally I would utilize that by doing something like `return.php?c=blahblah` but I'm not sure how to get that functionality into the AJAX code above....

I'm SO close to getting this to work!

Comment: `var lines = <?php echo $_SESSION['lines']; ?>;` And then you send that in Ajax?  Wait a minute, why would you send something that's already on the server (i.e. in the session) over Ajax?  Its already on the server...so its a total waste of bandwidth to send it back to the server, isn't it? (Those are rhetorical questions.)

Comment: Good point - My issue is that the first I load return.php, $_SESSION[lines] isn't set, so I set it using the $_SESSION[lines'] = $_REQUEST['lines'];  The next time I load the page (from dropdown.php), I guess the REQUEST doesn't work anymore?  So I have to wrap it in a if (!$_SESSION['lines'].  Wrapping it in the if statement solved that problem though!  Now what about getting "c" to populate?

Answer (score 0):

Think the issue is in your Selection of the Value:

```
<select onChange="selectCustomer(this.value)">
```

The `select` element has `option` elements within it. When an option is selected, you need to find that option's value. I usually leverage JQuery and that would looke like this:

```
$("select").on("change", function(){
  var optVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  selectCustomer(optVal);
});
```

Looking up JS, something like this:

```
<select onChange="selectCustomer(document.getElementsByTagName('option')[this.selectedIndex].value)">
```

Also what @developerwjk said.

Comment: I think of the two issues, we fixed one above - I stopped trying to set a session variable again, but now I'm stuck on what terminology I use to send `id` back to return.php, and to get it once I'm on return.php.  I think that's all i have left.  I've changed the ajax call to read `data: {c:id},`, so I think that sends the variable `id` over to return.php as a variable named `c`, but I don't know if that's correct, or how to get it on return.php....

Comment: aaaaaaand I figured it out.  I just needed to change return.php to read `$c = $_POST['c'];` instead of `$c = $_GET['c'];`

Comment: `$_POST[]` and `$_GET[]`, very useful! You can't mix them up though. Glad to hear you resolved it.